# Application of Extreme Value Theory in banking liquidity risk analysis

Tags: liquidity, banking-regulations, evt

The regulator forces banks to assess their (intraday) liquidity risk in normal and stressed conditions [see e.g. BCBS 144 principle 9](https://www.bis.org/publ/bcbs144.pdf).
To me this sounds pretty much like a possible application of EVT to banking  - not (!) asset - liquidity.

However, I find it hard to find referenes of an application of EVT to the liquidity of banks -especially something up-to-date.
Can we collect some here?

EDIT: I found [this thesis: Intraday liquidity risk estimation
using transaction data:
an extreme value theory approach](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A1c0c4545-bb07-4916-aa37-1d4bea3b7872). If I interpret the conclusions correctly then the result is rather mixed.

Comment: I've always found it hard to get stable calibrations of EVT to data from the world of finance

Comment: @BrianB I can see that for financial market data as well but does your remark hold for transaction data as well? As we discuss I would be interest to see a study. I will mention a thesis above that does this ... I wonder whether there is more material to read.